# Deploying a dacpac stored in a Storage Account using SqlPackage.exe

Tags: azure-sql-database, cicd

So I'm trying to deploy an Azure SQL database through CI/CD pipelines, using SqlPackage.exe in an Azure CLI task on DevOps. The dacpac which I am using to deploy is stored in Blob Storage, where I am storing every version of the artifact that is built, so I can rollback.

The issue is, I don't see any parameter to pass a URL as the source file. The only source file parameter is /sf, and if I try to pass a URL there, the error I get is  "Could not load package from '...my-url...'. The given path's format is not supported". Any ideas on how I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official MS docs on [SqlPackage for Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-for-azure-synapse-analytics?view=sql-server-ver15)

> [image]

Where as below would refer DACPAC stored in local machine.

[image]